# Iterating over a collection in Swift: var vs. let

Tags: xcode, swift2

I have a method that iterates over an array and call other method with every element as argument. If I declare this method as:

```
func didFinishedListFiles(files: [FileModel]) {
    for var fileData in files {
        self.downloadSingleFile(NSUUID(UUIDString: fileData.uuid!)!);
    }
}
```

Xcode shows a warning:

> Variable 'fileData' was never mutated; consider changing to 'let' constant

But if I change `var` to `let`:

```
func didFinishedListFiles(files: [FileModel]) {
    for let fileData in files {
        self.downloadSingleFile(NSUUID(UUIDString: fileData.uuid!)!);
    }
}
```

Xcode shows an error:

> 'let' pattern cannot appear nested in an already immutable context

How is a correct way to implement it without any warnings/errors?

Comment: Isn't it just `for fileData in files {...`. No var or let needed.

Comment: Thanks, you are right... ehhh

Comment: You're welcome. I think it implicitly makes it a `let` and if you want to mutate the object in the collection then you have to explicitly set it as `var`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `for`-`in` pattern implicitly uses a constant binding (in the scope it creates. That is, your `fileData` binding is automatically a local `let`, and therefore constant for each pass through the loop.

So the following:

```
for fileData in files { /*...*/ }
```

...is equivalent to :

```
var index = 0
while index < files.count {
    let fileData = files[index]
    //...
    index += 1
}
```

You'd want to add `var` to the `for`-`in` binding only when you want to mutate that binding -- that is, if it's an object reference that you want to be able to point at something else during a single pass through the loop, or a value type that you want to be able to change. But it doesn't look like you're doing either of those things, so using `var` for this binding would be superfluous here.

(Swift 3 got rid of a lot of the places where you could make implicitly immutable bindings mutable, but left `for var` as an exception — it's still possible if you want to change something during a loop.)

Comment: remove the `let` or `var` so it will be `for fileData in files` in this case.